# How to timely auto update Parse database

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using Parse database with javascript apis

I needed a functionality to remove a row from database table after 3 hours of its insertion

Suppose in a table "ShopBag"
it has a boolean attribute named "confirmed"

row when inserted in table,the value of this attribute is false.

but if it remains false for more than 3 hours, the row should be auto-deleted from the table.

Thanking in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a [cloud code background job](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs) and [scheduling](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs-scheduling). You'll need to create a job that searches for shopping bags that are greater than 3 hours old, and destroy them.

You will also need to then schedule the task. You could get it to repeat every minute, but this may be overkill depending on the volume of bags, or how close to the 3 hours you need to be.